# Get the last 15 weeks of data

Tags: sql-server

I need some help :-)

I'm working on a graph to get the last 15 weeks of data from the current day.

```
SELECT   count(*) AS nbUsers, DATEPART(week,u.USR_JOINED_DT) week
from [USR_USER] u
INNER JOIN [USI_USER_SITE] s ON u.USR_ID = s.USR_ID
where u.[USR_JOINED_DT] >=  DATEADD(DAY, -105, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY DATEPART(week,u.USR_JOINED_DT)
```

It gives me a result but not the good one, because it not starts from the current day.

Anybody have an idea on this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you're missing an ORDER BY expression

i.e. ORDER BY u.USR_JOINED_DT DESC

Answer (score 1):

Include an `ORDER BY` clause on your SQL statement:

```
SELECT   count(*) AS nbUsers, DATEPART(week,u.USR_JOINED_DT) week
from [USR_USER] u
INNER JOIN [USI_USER_SITE] s ON u.USR_ID = s.USR_ID
where u.[USR_JOINED_DT] >=  DATEADD(DAY, -105, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY DATEPART(week,u.USR_JOINED_DT)
ORDER BY u.[USR_JOINED_DT] --Ensures the data is ordered chronologically
```

Without an `ORDER BY` clause, SQL will find the quickest way to give you back the results. 9/10 this is the primary key.

Comment: In fact I would like to have the begin date of the week in the week's column.

Comment: @DavidSautet Does my answer solve your initial question? Are you now asking a new question?